# Why is it true that if the integral is finite then $\lim_{s\to\infty} \int_{s}^{\infty} f(x) dx=0$?

Tags: integration, limits

I saw it whilst reading my lecture notes that

> Let $f(x)$ be integrable such that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) dx<\infty$ then it means that $\lim_{s\to\infty} \int_{s}^{\infty} f(x) dx=0.$

I can't seem to understand why such deduction can be made. I can believe such statement but is there a solid reason behind this? (P.S. I not thinking either Lebesgue Integration or Riemann Integration but just Integration in general, if it helps.)

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick proof:

$${\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)dx = \int_{0}^{s}f(x)dx + \int_{s}^{\infty}f(x)dx}$$

By definition, ${\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)dx=\lim_{s\rightarrow\infty}\int_{0}^{s}f(x)dx}$. Denote ${\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)dx}$ as ${L}$. Then you see

$${\lim_{s\rightarrow\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)dx = \lim_{s\rightarrow\infty}\int_{0}^{s}f(x)dx + \int_{s}^{\infty}f(x)dx}$$

$${\Rightarrow L=L + \lim_{s\rightarrow \infty}\int_{s}^{\infty}f(x)dx}$$

So you see that

$${\lim_{s\rightarrow\infty}\int_{s}^{\infty}f(x)dx}$$

**must** ${=0}$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Set $g^{(s)} := f \chi_{(s, \infty)}$, where $\chi_A$ is the charackteristic function of $A$, and use Lebesgue's Theorem.

Comment: This assumes absolute integrability of $f$, which I don't think the asker is assuming

Comment: Yes, that is true.