# Corollary of Cauchy Criterion for Integrals

Tags: real-analysis

By definition, if $\int_{s}^{\infty}f(x)\;\text{d}x$ converges then for all $\varepsilon>0$ there eixsts $M$ such that for $m_{2}>m_{1}>M$ :
$$
\left|\int_{m_{1}}^{m_{2}}f(x)\;\text{d}x\right|<\varepsilon
$$

My main question is how can we deduce that $\lim_{s\to\infty}\int_{s}^{\infty}f(x)\;\text{d}x=0$ using Cauchy's Criterion? I thought of using contradiction that is to assume the limit exists denote it as $L$ and consider two cases $L>0$ and $L<0$ and conclude that it is only the case of $L=0$ which is the one required, would this be an application of Cauchy Criterion?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is it true that if the integral is finite then $\lim_{s\to\infty} \int_{s}^{\infty} f(x) dx=0$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3749197/why-is-it-true-that-if-the-integral-is-finite-then-lim-s-to-infty-int-s)